# Page flickering in chrome - bootstrap & jquery conflict

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am having an issue of my webpage **flickering/blinking randomly, this happens in chrome**, I have not yet tested other browsers.

I figured that this issue **should be due to bootstrap.js & jQuery.js conflict** because **if I remove one of these then it does not blink no more, it doesn't matter which one I remove.**

I tryed to use the `jquery-noConflict()` method but either I don't know how to use it properly or it did not wok for me.

But removing both any of them is not an option because some of the websites features are not working then.

I have recorded how it looks while it flickers:
removed

It is hard for me to describe the problem when I am limited to uploading images and links as I am a new member of stackoverflow, as I can only post 2 links, I'll post the link of the website, so if anybody can help me they can look over the source code there freely - http://removed

I am using **jquery-1.11.0.min.js** and  **bootstrap.min.js**

This is one of the blocks that flickers:

```
<section id="privalumai" class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12 title">
      <h2>Privalumai</h2>
      <span class="underline">&nbsp;</span>
    </div>
    <!-- Service Box start -->
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="service-box wow fadeInLeft" data-wow-offset="100">
        <div class="service-icon">+</div>
        <h3 class="service-title">Draudimas</h3>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
        <p class="service-content">Visos mÅ«sÅ³ transporto priemonÄ—s yra apdraustos tiek KASKO, tiek privalomuoju ( TPVCA ) draudimu. Kasko draudimo galiojimo teritorija â€“ geografinÄ— Europa, o TPVCA â€“ â€žÅ¾aliosios kortelÄ—sâ€œ sistemos ribose.
            Jums pageidaujant, galime pasiÅ«lyti ir vykstanÄiÅ³ Ä¯ uÅ¾sienÄ¯ kompleksinÄ¯  kelionÄ—s draudimÄ… ( pvz. vykstant slidinÄ—ti ir pan.)<br/><br/></p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Service Box end -->
    <!-- Service Box start -->
      <div class="col-md-6">
          <div class="service-box wow fadeInLeft" data-wow-offset="100">
              <div class="service-icon">+</div>
              <h3 class="service-title">Mobilumas</h3>
              <div class="clearfix"></div>
              <p class="service-content">Visos mÅ«sÅ³ transporto priemonÄ—s yra naujos ir yra aprÅ«pintos tiek pilna gamintojo garantija, tiek techninÄ—s pagalbos kelyje paslauga, todÄ—l tiek avarijos ar techninio gedimo atveju Jums bus suteiktas pakaitinis automobilis  ir pasirÅ«pinta JÅ«sÅ³ kelionÄ—s pratÄ™simu.<br/><br/><br/></p>
          </div>
      </div>
    <!-- Service Box end -->
    <!-- Service Box start -->
      <div class="col-md-6">
          <div class="service-box wow fadeInRight" data-wow-offset="100">
              <div class="service-icon">+</div>
              <h3 class="service-title">Neribotas kilometrÅ³ kiekis</h3>
              <div class="clearfix"></div>
              <p class="service-content">Mes suprantame savo klientÅ³ poreikius, todÄ—l neribojame jÅ³ nuvaÅ¾iuoto kilometrÅ³ kiekio.<br/><br/></p>
          </div>
      </div>
    <!-- Service Box end -->
    <!-- Service Box start -->
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="service-box wow fadeInRight" data-wow-offset="100">
        <div class="service-icon">+</div>
        <h3 class="service-title">Nauji automobiliai</h3>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
        <p class="service-content">MÅ«sÅ³ transporto priemonÄ—s yra naujos ir sukomplektuotos taip, kad Jums bÅ«tÅ³ patogu ir lengva keliauti.<br/><br/></p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Service Box end -->
  </div>
</section>
```

I am really lost here and now sure how would I go about fixing this. I would really appreciate if somebody would point me at the right direction. **If there aren't enough resources or anything else please comment and I will supply them and reply to all of your answers!**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does adding this to your flickering element solve it?

```
.flickeringElementFix {
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}
```

It could be that there's some element manipulation going on in one or both of your scripts that are arguing

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_backface-visibility.asp

Comment: This worked, along with: "backface-visibility: hidden;"

Comment: Nice, i'll update the answer to include that for future refrence

Comment: Thanks @NachoDawg, it works for me. I still don't understand how"hiding the back" of the element helps in the flickering? What cause it in the first place?

Comment: @HoàngLong I have to preface that I am not entirely sure myself.. When a block is animated (I am not sure the criteria for this is), like Daniel N's "fadeInLeft" divs for example, the browser tries to create a 3d element. "backface-visibility:hidden;" makes the browser not "render" the back-side of the 3d element, making the animation easier to load. We don't need the backside of the 3d element because there's not a case where the user needs to see it

Comment: *to add, I think Daniel N had the problem of having 2 scripts trying to animate the same thing. Using this new CSS property, we did not prevent both scripts for doing this, but we made the workload lighter so both scripts could run without glitching

Comment: I see. That means it just temporarily prevent the issue... "When I have time", I will need to check more into it.